# A letter in a byte? C#

Tags: c#, c++

I have an imported C++ method that receives a byte parameter, but according to the documentation, I can send a letter to that parameter, this is the C++ and C# method:

```
int WINAPI Sys_InitType(HID_DEVICE device, BYTE type)

public static extern int Sys_InitType(IntPtr device, byte type);
```

This causes me a syntax error in C#, how do I send a letter in that parameter?

My code (A bit random):

```
//CRASHES
byte random = Convert.ToByte("A");
_ = RFIDReader.Sys_SetAntenna(g_hDevice, 0);
int lol = RFIDReader.Sys_InitType(g_hDevice, random);
_ = RFIDReader.Sys_SetAntenna(g_hDevice, 1);
CError.Text = lol.ToString();
```

[image: Documentation of the method]

Comment: "A" is a string, not a character. Try `byte random = (byte)'A'`

Comment: @KlausGütter It Worked, ty!

Comment: `Convert.ToByte('A')` should also work as far as I can tell.

Comment: C# strings are Unicode, and `Char` can only be cast to an `int` without the risk of losing data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Convert.ToByte(string);` doesn't do what you think it does, according to the documentation

> Converts the specified string representation of a number to an equivalent 8-bit unsigned integer.

This would work `byte random = Conver.ToByte("52");` which will return the `byte` `52`.

See here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.convert.tobyte?view=net-6.0#system-convert-tobyte(system-string)

As was pointed out in the comment already, you will have to use character instead of string, so either this

```
byte random = Convert.ToByte('A');
```

or a simple cast to byte

```
byte random = (byte)'A'
```

In case it is unknown to you, which I didn't assume, a byte can only contain values of the range 0 - 255, while a character can contain everything within the specs of UTF-16.

So this will not work

```
byte random = Convert.ToByte('\u4542');
```

And result in the error:

> Value was either too large or too small for an unsigned byte.

https://dotnetfiddle.net/anjxt5

Comment: Strings in .NET are Unicode and a `Char` requires an `int`, otherwise the high byte will be lost. This cast only works because the high byte for `A` is 0

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos - edited the answer